# Angular 6 build "404 page not found" with 2 routing modules

Tags: angular, web, module, routes

My problem is simple, I have a Angular website with 3 routing.module. (One for the home, login, signup, ... And 2 others interfaces). I would like to create one general page not found (404).

**Because if I wrote that:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'feedback',
    component: FeedbackComponent
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: ErrorNotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404'
  }
}
```

**In my main app.routing.module the other path in my other routing module are not working.**

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a  `/` in front of `404` - like this `redirectTo: '/404'`?

Comment: it doesn't working, I'm automatically redirected to 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I have a multi routing architecture so I have needed to create a new routing module only for the errors and add it add the end of my other routing modules.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Worked perfectly for me.